# Would it be appropriate to ask a question too hard to answer?

Tags: discussion

There is some question very specific and hard to answer. Not because it's too broad, but because the answer is too difficult to find.

I can give you an example with one of [my own question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258238/if-two-armies-arriving-on-the-same-day-which-one-is-attacking-defending). In this case, it's impossible to find the answer on the web actually and it cannot be tested in the game because the probability of that kind of event happening is too small.

When I read the question, with hindsight, I realize I'll probably never get an answer on this one because it would require to be answered by a Paradox's game designer or coder.

**Is it right to ask that kind of question ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are speculating that someone doesn't have additional tricks up their google sleeves or was able to test out the problem in game using tools or methods beyond your knowledge.  Furthermore, someone who has put many hours into the game may have enough experience to provide an answer.

If not answers, the same events could also trigger useful comments that help find answers.

In other words, one day someone may answer the question.

There are plenty of unanswered questions on this site.

Assuming the question doesn't fall foul of the off-topic list, there shouldn't be a reason for closing such questions.

Answer (score 12):

Worst case scenario, you won't get any answer.

That is not a good reason for us to close the question.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed